# Group cohomology of symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, group-cohomology

Let $p \neq 2$ be a prime, $\Sigma_p$ be the symmetric group on $p$ elements, and $Z_{(p)}$ be the integers localized at $p$.

Let $G$ be a finite group with Sylow $p$-subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/p$ and $\Sigma_p \subset G$.

Then we have

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
H^*(G,\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}) = H^*(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})^W
\end{equation}

where $W\subset \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is the image of the normalizer $N(\mathbb{Z}/p) \subset G$ in $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ under the natural action of $N(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p$ (The superscript denotes invariants here, I think, in the sense that it is the submodule that's unchanged under the action of $W$).

We have a theorem that if $G$ is a finite group with $H$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup, then $\text{res}^G_H$ maps $H^n(G,M)_{(p)}$ isomorphically onto the set of $G$-invariant elements of $H^n(H,M)$, where $H^n(G,M)_{(p)}$ is the $p$-primary component of $H^n(G,M)$. Here the invariants are defined as follows:
Let $G$ be an arbitrary group and $H \subset G$. An element $z \in H^*(H,M)$ is $G$-invariant if $\text{res}^H_{H\subset gHg^{-1}}z = \text{res}^{gHg^{-1}}_{H \cap gHg^{-1}} gz$ for all $g\in G$. It is known that if $z = \text{res}^G_H w$ for some $w\in H^*(H,M)$, then $z$ is $G$-invariant. Here res is the standard restriction map in group cohomology, $\text{res}^G_H: H^*(G,M) \to H^*(H,M)$.

My questions concerning this isomorphism are:

1. Does the "natural action" of $N(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p$ refer to conjugation by the element in the normalizer?
2. I don't understand why $H^*(\mathbb{Z}/p,\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})^W$ is the $G$-invariant elements. If that's the case, then we're done here.

---

Define the holomorph $H = \mathbb{Z}/p \rtimes \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ (with the identity map in the semidirect product); it is known that we can embed $H$ in $\Sigma_p$. Since $H \subset \Sigma_p\subset G$, then the restriction map
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
H^*(G; \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}) \to H^*(\Sigma_p;\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})
\end{equation}
is an isomorphism.
Here I don't understand why we get the isomorphism above. Could someone explain?

Comment: We have a lot of detailed, precise notations, describing groups containing other groups, and coefficient systems. The questions are not so precise. What are "invariants"? What does the following mean exactly: "equality and isomorphism concerning group cohomology"?

Comment: @kg1 I tried to interpret the question to make it a bit more precise (it can still be improved for the first question), is it faithful to what you wanted to ask ?

Comment: Thanks both to your reply. I've edited my question to make it clearer. Could you look at it again? Thank you!